# Setting up arguments for multiple buttons on same page? Total newbie question

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function go_there()
{
 var where_to= confirm("Do you really want to go to this page??");
 if (where_to== true)
 {
   window.location="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xxxx";
 }
 else
 {
  window.location="#";
  }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

and this on the button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="signup_button3" onClick="go_there()"><span class="floatbutton">Get It! $10</span></a>
```

I know this is a simple thing involving setting up arguments correctly, but I'm still quite new and trying to figure this out...

I will have several buttons on the same page and when user clicks the buttons, I want the same popup to happen, but they will be taken to a different paypal checkout for each button.  Can you show me how to do that?

And lastly, can the popup button handle things like unordered lists?

Thank you!
Joel

Edit:figured out my first issue and so edited question...sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" onclick="go_there('http://...')" value="press me">
<script type="text/javascript">

function go_there(loc)
{
 var where_to= confirm("Do you really want to go to this page??");
 if (where_to)
 {
   document.location=loc;
 }

}
</script>
```

I'm not clear on your part about ordered lists. pop-ups are HTML pages, like any other.

Comment: That worked great.  Thank you!  Where would I do the html for the pop-up though?

Comment: In place of "document.location=loc". "loc" will be the URL to use for the pop-up.